# .Net Core MVC - TempData not saving data locally in AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

This did work for me some time back. I haven't changed the code surrounding this area, and now it doesn't work.

I have a .net core 2.2 MVC web app, which fires an AJAX call when the user wants to download a file (word document, 60KB in size). The AJAX call triggers my `HTTPPost` controller method which retrieves the file, and stores it to `TempData`.

The success callback of my AJAX call then triggers a `HTTPGET` controller method which reads from TempData and sends the file back to the user to download. Its in this method where TempData is null. I am running this locally within iis express

AJAX Call code:

```
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/DownloadFileAJAX",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { data: downloadUrl },
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result == "success") {                                   
                            var filepath = JSON.stringify(result);
                            alert('Successfully called' + filepath);                                    
                            location.href = '@Url.Action("ActuallyDownloadFile", "Home")';                                 
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        if (result == "failed")
                            alert('Failed' + result);
                        alert("An error has occured in ajax call!" + JSON.stringify(result));
                    }
                });
```

First controller method that my AJAX call triggers:

```
[HttpPost]   
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadFileAJAX(string data)
{
    string code = "";
    string toBeSearched = _configuration.GetValue<string>("ReferralDownloadSearchParameter");         
    int ix = data.IndexOf(toBeSearched);

    if (ix != -1)
    {
        code = data.Substring(ix + toBeSearched.Length);
    }

    var referralUploadPath = _configuration.GetValue<string>("ReferralFormLocation");
    var path = string.Concat(referralUploadPath, "", code);

    var memory = new MemoryStream();
    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
    }
    memory.Position = 0;

    TempData["ReferralOutput"] = memory.ToArray();
    TempData["FileName"] = code;
    return Json("success", new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings());       

}
```

Second controller method that my AJAX call triggers:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ActuallyDownloadFile()
{
    // retrieve byte array here
    var filenameReferral = TempData["FileName"];
    var array = TempData["ReferralOutput"] as byte[];
    if (array != null)
    {                
        return File(array, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingm", filenameReferral.ToString());                
    }
    else
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

Screenshot to show values at runtime:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH9wZ.jpg

Any idea what is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Any update? Does my reply help you?

Comment: That did work buddy many thanks, apologies for the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your codes, I have created a test demo on my side, it works well.  As far as I know, the temp data is stored in the cookie by default. If you disable the cookie or match the cookie limit . It will not work well.

Most browsers restrict cookie size to 4096 bytes. Only a limited number of cookies are available for each domain.

I suggest you could try to use AddSessionStateTempDataProvider to let the temp data stored into the session instead of cookie.

Notice: The session still need cookie enabled, since the session id is stored at cookie.

More details about how to enable the AddSessionStateTempDataProvider , you could refer to below codes:

ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews()
        .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();

    services.AddSession();
}
```

Configure method:

add  `app.UseSession();`

Result as below:

[image]

Comment: Hello. I am experiencing the same problem in ASP.NET MVC 6 project, but I already have the configuration that you mentioned. Still, it is not working.
I am firing 3 parallel async AJAX-es which consume 3 mvc endpoints from the same controller, TempData is not persisted through the calls. Each call successfully manipulates the TempData but also overrides it. So, only the last call data is available. I also use Peek() and Keep() methods. Any help is welcome :)